# Как изменить код, чтобы можно было открыть несколько подряд подпунктов меню?

Tags: jquery

```js
$('#menu li.has-sub > a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
  var element = $(this).parent('li');
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
    element.removeClass('open');
    element.find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.find('ul').slideUp();
  } else {
    element.addClass('open');
    element.children('ul').slideDown();
    element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
    element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='menu'>
  <ul>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Колличество ламп</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_1">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_1" value="1" />
              <span>1</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_2">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_2" value="2" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_3">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_3" value="3" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Тип лампочек</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_4">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_4" value="4" />
              <span>1</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_5">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_5" value="5" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_6">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_6" value="6" />
              <span>3</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Применение</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_7">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_7" value="7" />
              <span>1</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_8">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_8" value="8" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_9">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_9" value="9" />
              <span>3</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Стиль</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_10">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_10" value="10" />
              <span>1</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_11">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_11" value="11" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_12">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_12" value="12" />
              <span>3</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Бренд</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_13">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_13" value="13" />
              <span>1</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_14">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_14" value="14" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_15">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_15" value="15" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

при клике по пункту меню, открывается подпункт с чекбокс, при клике по втором (первый закрывается) и т.д. как изменить код, чтобы можно было открыть несколько подпунктов меню подряд, ну и соответственно их потом закрыть?

Comment: не делать slideup для соседних и они не будут закрываться

Comment: можно подробнее, ибо я уже перепробовал как угодно и ничего не выходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ветке `else` в строках

```
element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
...
element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
```

<sub>Кстати, почти одно и то же делается и можно оставить только последнюю строчку.</sub>

Выбираются `ul`, которые находятся в соседних с текущим `li`. Если закомментировать эту строчку, они не будут закрываться.

В принципе весь метод можно заменить на следующее

```js
$('#menu li.has-sub > a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
  var element = $(this).parent('li')
                       .toggleClass('open')
                       .children('ul')
                       .slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='menu'>
  <ul>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Колличество ламп</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_1">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_1" value="1" />
              <span>1</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_2">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_2" value="2" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_3">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_3" value="3" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Тип лампочек</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_4">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_4" value="4" />
              <span>1</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_5">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_5" value="5" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_6">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_6" value="6" />
              <span>3</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Применение</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_7">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_7" value="7" />
              <span>1</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_8">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_8" value="8" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_9">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_9" value="9" />
              <span>3</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Стиль</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_10">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_10" value="10" />
              <span>1</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_11">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_11" value="11" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_12">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_12" value="12" />
              <span>3</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Бренд</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_13">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_13" value="13" />
              <span>1</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_14">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_14" value="14" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <label for="label_15">
              <input type="checkbox" name="animalc" id="label_15" value="15" />
              <span>2</span>
            </label>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```